# How to set the window's icon

Tags: c#, winforms, icons

I was wondering how you would set the icon for the window in c#. I have found answers, but the answer does not involve programming. In visual studio they have an application builder, but I would like to program my application instead. Does anyone know who to accomplish this simple task?

This is what I have so far:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.Run(new window());
    }
}

class Window : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    public static String Title = "This is a title!";

    public Window()
    {
        this.Size = new Size(640, 480);
        this.Text = Title;
    }
}
```

Comment: The application builder sets all the attributes, properties and icon things in the xml file.

Comment: Can I change the xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the designer:

1. Open the designer.
2. Click on the window.
3. Open Properties pane (F4).
4. Locate the `Icon` row and click on it.
5. Click on the `...` Button.

[image]

Alternativaly, you can do it in code:

```
string pathToIcon =@"C:\Path\To\Icon.ico"
this.Icon = new Icon(pathToIcon );
```

Comment: How do you access files that are in a folder in your project? I keep getting an error message saying it can find the file. I did an empty project. I am not seeing what you have dispalyed

Comment: @user3150101 I am not sure I understand your question. Is the Icon part of the resources of your project?

Comment: The icon is in a folder in my project.

Comment: I found out how to do it:

this.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(@"C:\Path\To\Icon.ico");

but it only changes the icon in the window and not on the task bar

Answer (score 1):

```
this.Icon = new Icon(@"C:\Folder\IconName.ico");
```

or if you are embedding the icon in the app:

```
this.Icon = new Icon(iconStream);
```